# How do I edit the values of a line chart using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have the following chart:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo7uV.png

As you can see, the Y axis is showing/tagging numbers from 10 to 25, and I need it to display from 0 to 100, breaking by 5.
Any ideas? Thanks!!

This is the code:

```
  ggplot(tabla4, aes(x = Año, y = per2, colour = Género)) +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "white") +
  ylab("Personas que simpatizan con un partido político") +
  xlab("") + 
  theme_gray(base_size = 12) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

And this info about my database:

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Año     : num  2006 2008 2010 2012 2014 ...
 $ Género  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Hombre","Mujer": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
 $ Simpatía: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Sí": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ Freq    : num  188 150 91 88 80 196 164 124 131 116
 $ countT  : num  677 601 738 557 503 ...
 $ per     : num  27.8 25 12.3 15.8 15.9 23.8 19 10.3 13.5 11.7
 $ per2    : num  0.278 0.25 0.123 0.158 0.159 0.238 0.19 0.103 0.135 0.117
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Your `per2` variable is between 0-1 as it looks like a percentage. You can enable `limits` and `breaks` inside `scale_y_continuous()` in order to obtain the expected output. If you want breaks each 5 units, you can define a sequence with `seq()` function using `by=0.05`. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(tabla4, aes(x = Año, y = per2, colour = Género)) +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "white") +
  ylab("Personas que simpatizan con un partido político") +
  xlab("") + 
  theme_gray(base_size = 12) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     limits = c(0,1),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.05))
```

As no data is provided, here a little reproducible example with dummy data to show how the new elements work (Please next time include a sample of your data):

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=seq(0,0.5,length.out = 10))
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     limits = c(0,1),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.05))
```

Output:

[image]

And using data similar to yours:

```
library(tidyverse)  
#Data 2
df <- data.frame(Año=c(2006,2008,2010,2012,2014),
                 Mujer=c(0.24,0.19,0.10,0.14,0.12),
                 Hombre=c(0.34, 0.29, 0.2, 0.24, 0.22))
#Plot
df %>% pivot_longer(-Año) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Año, y = value, colour = name)) +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "white") +
  ylab("Personas que simpatizan con un partido político") +
  xlab("") + 
  theme_gray(base_size = 12) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     limits = c(0,1),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.05))
```

Output:

[image]

You can try any customization on `breaks` option.

Comment: Thanks! do you have any idea about how to switch the colours???

Comment: @BrunoRodríguez Sure, you can add at the final of the code `scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue'))` or any colors you wish. Just do no forget to use `+` as in the entire structure!